# Saving CKAsset to CKRecord in CloudKit produces error: "No authToken received for asset"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

This is the full error message I am getting when I try to save a `CKAsset` to a `CKRecord`. I haven't seen this error before nor can I find any information about it *anywhere*.

Has anyone heard of this before?

```
<CKError 0x17064ccf0: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; partial errors: {
    4B1CD9BE-3B67-49C5-AC39-F8379A5041C9:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x174451a90: "Internal Error" (1/1000); "No authToken received for asset">
    AC51EFE8-E370-4286-9510-B86B24855BE8:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x174451880: "Internal Error" (1/1000); "No authToken received for asset">
    D52322DA-2E13-46EF-B58F-9B74D97CE876:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x174451430: "Internal Error" (1/1000); "No authToken received for asset">
}>
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Thunk I found a workaround which was to make a local copy of the image/video locally and then use that url for the `CKAsset`

Comment: I've learned a little more about when this happens, and documented my findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983391/cloudkit-error-no-authtoken-received-for-asset/44988664#44988664